# Why gradle cache can be slow?

Tags: android, performance, android-studio, gradle, build

I have the next situation:
Android project with about `680` modules
and `~300k` files in folder(including .git) of `~4GB` total size
(growing to `600-700k` files when build is finished).

I placed my project folder on NVME M.2 SSD drive
and when I'm building it, I see that tasks like

> somemodule:sometask > cleaning stale outputs 
> somemodule2:sometask2 > unpacking build cache entry

passing fast in the beginning, then slower, slower, and slower.
About 50-60% of total build progress 
I see that mostly all currently building modules are taking quite a long time with that steps.
Modules building in parallel (12 threads on CPU => 12 build tasks in parallel).

So my build is taking some hours (may be **up to 5 hours**).
Also I noticed, that SSD drive Active Time are falling from 15-30% in the beginning
to 0-1%, and read/write speeds become low (less than 1 megabyte per second).
(As indicated in Windows TaskManager)

Although, If i'm placing that project folder into an *.img file (probably img/vhd/vhdx/vmdk don't matter)
and mounting as Virtual Drive (for example with OSFMount),
or ever further, i'm mounting that in RAM,
then all the build goes fast and taking **about 30-60 minutes**.
And when everything is built and cached, repeated build takes about 3-4 minutes
(that's in a project with 10k-15k tasks executed).

So I'm calling for help
in finding root cause of the problem.

Some technical info:
Windows 10 21H2
Gradle plugin 7.2
Build stats example:

```
BUILD SUCCESSFUL in 12m 52s
14692 actionable tasks: 696 executed, 13299 from cache, 697 up-to-date
Configuration cache entry reused.
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm sorry, it was our internal issue.
Information Security team in company
placed antivirus and some activity monitoring utility "searchinformagent", so they both made a lot of file checking and crazy disk performance damage.